# How to animate a CSS-loaded SVG background with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, animation, svg

I have the following SVG (shortened version).

```css
.line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500vh;
  margin-top: 100px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  background:
    linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff, transparent) top/100% 1024px no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(to top, #fff, transparent) bottom/100% 128px no-repeat,
    url(line.svg) top/768px;
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  width="200px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 200 200" enable-background="new 0 0 200 200" xml:space="preserve">
  <style>
   path {
    transition: opacity 512ms ease-in-out;
   }

   .rise {
    opacity: 0.2;
   }

   .fall {
    opacity: 1;
   }
  </style>
<g>
 <path fill="#070707" d="M109.021,87.07c1.871,1.233,1.874,3.713,3.569,5.022c0.051-0.372,0.073-0.78,0.042-1.163l-0.426-0.236
  c2.157-5.078-5.299-7.254-8.281-7.586c-2.127-0.236-4.292-0.489-6.372-1.008c-2.521-0.63-3.054-1.987-4.201-4.195
  c-0.397,5.932,5.381,6.908,9.51,7.333C104.642,85.419,107.502,86.07,109.021,87.07z"/>
 <path fill="#070707" d="M200,199.422c-0.219,0.195-0.438,0.391-0.664,0.58H200V199.422z"/>
</g>
 <script type="text/javascript"><![CDATA[
   var els = document.querySelectorAll('path')

   for (var i = 0, n = els.length; i < n; i++) {
    var el = els[i]
    animateIn(el, Math.floor(Math.random() * 2048))
   }

   function animateIn(el, stagger) {
    setTimeout(function(){
     el.classList.add('rise')
     animateOut(el, 512)
    }, stagger)
   }

   function animateOut(el, stagger) {
    setTimeout(function(){
     el.classList.add('fall')
     animateIn(el, 512)
    }, stagger)
   }
 ]]></script>
</svg>
```

I don't think that works, but it's the gist of the code. Basically, I have added some JavaScript *straight to the SVG*, to animate the opacity *of each separate path* in and out. I want it to sort of "sparkle".

But this isn't working if I style an element with this `.line` class. It successfully draws the SVG in a repeating fashion, but it doesn't do the animation. I'm wondering how to accomplish this. I don't want to use a purely inline SVG which I could directly animate in a similar way, *because I want to use this SVG on multiple pages* and don't want to load it inline on each page. But if that's the only way to do it that would be good to know.

Do I need something like [this](https://github.com/jamesmartin/remote-svg/blob/master/lib/src/remote_svg.js)?

Basically my HTML document is like this:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <section>something</section>
    <section class='line'></section>
    <section>something else</section>
  </body>
</html>
```

The `.line` class sets the CSS background-image to the `line.svg` file.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT3 (FINAL):** What I alluded to in EDIT2 below IS possible and here it is, since I don't have your "line.svg" and I wanted to show a working snippet, I just inlined svg binary into my css , *this should be interchangeable with a proper svg file* (as in: if .line had background: url("line.svg") it will work identically to my example)

Next time PLEASE post the whole question *before* publishing. That took **way** too many edits due to the question being changed.

```css
@keyframes shine {
  0% {
    opacity: .2;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.line {
  /*transition: opacity 512ms ease-in-out;*/
  animation: shine 1s ease-in-out infinite;

width: 50px;
height: 50px;
background: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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') 50% 50% no-repeat;
background-size: 100%; }
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <section>something</section>
    <section class='line'></section>
    <section>something else</section>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

**EARLIER (before Question-er updated question)**
If I understand your question and code - you want to have that same 'fade-in and out' effect but without the inline javascript. You can seperate js from the html and add that svg path **with js**.

```js
window.onload=function() {
  var line=document.getElementsByClassName("line")[0];
  console.log(line);
  /* not sure why I had to concatonate the various pieces, prob because of the code snippet editor in SO */
  line.innerHTML='<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="200px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 200 200" enable-background="new 0 0 200 200" xml:space="preserve">'+
'<g>'+
 '<path class="myPath" fill="#070707" d="M109.021,87.07c1.871,1.233,1.874,3.713,3.569,5.022c0.051-0.372,0.073-0.78,0.042-1.163l-0.426-0.236'+
  'c2.157-5.078-5.299-7.254-8.281-7.586c-2.127-0.236-4.292-0.489-6.372-1.008c-2.521-0.63-3.054-1.987-4.201-4.195'+
  'c-0.397,5.932,5.381,6.908,9.51,7.333C104.642,85.419,107.502,86.07,109.021,87.07z"/>' +
 '<path class="myPath" fill="#070707" d="M200,199.422c-0.219,0.195-0.438,0.391-0.664,0.58H200V199.422z"/>'+
'</g>'+
'</svg>';
};
```

```css
.line {
  /*transition: opacity 512ms ease-in-out;*/
  animation: shine 1s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes shine {
  0% {
    opacity: .2;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <section>something</section>
    <section class='line'></section>
    <section>something else</section>
  </body>
</html>
```

**NOTE: the above is the OLD snippet, please scroll up in same answer for the final answer which is in the first snippet**

**EDIT2:** ...I believe it *may* be doable without js, by bringing in line.svg as the background for .line elements and using my css to animate it, but it's bed-time :)...

Comment: I've added some more to the bottom of the post explaining how my HTML document is structured.

Comment: Yep - noticed. I had to edit the code and my comments a few times to make my answer fit the revised question AND (hopefully) also make some sense to those who didn't see both versions of the questions. 'tis all good, have a good night :)

Comment: No, I want to edit the individual lines _inside the SVG_. Say the SVG is a pen and ink illustration. I want to animate each pen stroke individually. But I want to use it as a CSS class, or otherwise host the SVG externally (i.e. not inline it). What you're describing is simply basic HTML animation which happens to use SVG as a background image. Very different.

Comment: There are 2 code snippets in this answer, go to the first one (the one w/ the owl looking icon for SVG), which has no JS at all! Whatever has the class "line" will have the SVG animated within it. That answers your (revised) problem: "...this isn't working if I style an element with this .line class. It successfully draws the SVG in a repeating fashion, but it doesn't do the animation."

Comment: If you are looking to change the actual SVG, i.e. to manipulate the <g> and <path>s - your question and example doesn't reflect that at all. That can (and should) be done with javascript.